# JQuery Nested onclick function running twice

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, onclick

I have used the document.ready function of JQuery with onlick function inside of it which is triggered when clicked the button with id="btn1" adding text before the image.

similar onclick button "btn2" function is inside of it which is adding text after the Image.

**The Problem I am facing is that when I run it 1st time all is working fine but when I click the "insert before" button 2nd time and then click "insert after", the text after is outputted 2 times.**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $("#check").before("<b>Before</b><button class='btn2'>Insert after</button>");
    $(".btn2").click(function(){
    $("#check").after("<i>After</i>");
  });
  });

  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>

<img id="check" src="/images/w3jquery.gif" alt="jQuery" width="100" height="140"><br><br>

<br>
<button id="btn1">Insert before</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not advice you to have a click event inside another click event.

What you need to is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#check").before("<b>Before</b><button class='btn2'>Insert after</button>");
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".btn2", function() {
    $("#check").after("<i>After</i>");
  });
});
```

What happens when you have a click event inside another click event is this:

Lets say we have `ClickEvent1` & `ClickEvent2`.

 `ClickEvent2` is inside `ClickEvent1`.

When `ClickEvent1` is triggered it will bind `ClickEvent2` to the selector.

 If you trigger `ClickEvent1` again, then you will bind `ClickEvent2` once more. That means if you trigger `ClickEvent2` it will run the code 2 times.

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("#check").before("<b>Before</b><button class='btn2'>Insert after</button>");
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".btn2", function() {
    $("#check").after("<i>After</i>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="check" src="/images/w3jquery.gif" alt="jQuery" width="100" height="140"><br><br>

<br>
<button id="btn1">Insert before</button>
```